# Where can I find a reputable site that distributes Maven 2.2.1?

Tags: maven

I need to install Maven 2.2.1, but the canonical site has removed the download links to it. Where can I find the older versions at? I'm looking for a reputable site, not some random share site like megaupload.

Comment: The reason why you don't find it on the offical download pages is described here: http://maven.apache.org/maven-2.x-eol.html. Why do you need 2.2.1 ?

Comment: Because I'm working on a legacy project that doesn't compile correctly under maven 3. Obviously upgrading to maven 3 would be the "correct answer" to this problem, but that isn't an immediate solution and I don't really own the entirety of the codebase, I'm just contributing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an archive for all the old Apache releases.

https://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/binaries/